# Python How to return the lists inside of list that has string number column higher than number

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists that got this values-

```py
firstList=['Black Mirror,Drama,2011,8.8', 'BoJack Horseman,animation,2014,8.7','Westworld,Drama,2016,8.7']
```

how can i do this: firstList.year<2015

And return this :

```py
secondList=['Black Mirror,Drama,2011,8.8', 'BoJack Horseman,Animation,2014,8.7']
```

Comment: Would be best to store this data in a dictionary. But what have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried with a for loop but i can't convert that string value to int and compare with a int and check which list inside that list fullfills that condition

Answer (score 0):

just use a for-loop and check each one:

```py
listB = []
for s in listA:
    if int(s.split(',')[2]) < 2015:
        listB.append(s)
```

or one-liner with list comprehension (basically the same thing):

```py
listB = [s for s in listA if int(s.split(',')[2]) < 2015]
```

and to sort the list by the rating you can do this: (if it isn't the way you want it use `reverse=True`)

```py
listB = sorted(listB, key=lambda s:float(s.split(',')[3]))
```

Comment: dude omg.. thank you.. im a beginner in python.. thanks for the help.
Love from portugal!

Comment: Is there anyway that i can sort the list by the last column in list(ranking)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a csv. Using for loops and formatting the values each time to add more conditions that'll help you find the required data will be a tedious task. I'd suggest using the pandas library since your data looks like that of a csv. And if you have a csv, it is much better to use this library.
The code would be:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

listA = ['Black Mirror,Drama,2011,8.8', 'BoJack Horseman,animation,2014,8.7', 'Westworld,Drama,2016,8.7']

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("\n".join(listA)), header=None)

result = df.loc[df[2] < 2015] #The main search line
```

In the line that performs the search note that `2` corresponds to the year column. This method will also allow you to perform some complex tasks easily. For example, sorting with the last column in descending order is as simple as `result = df.sort_values(3, ascending=False)`

And to print the names as stored in `result` after performing the search or sort operation:

```py
for row in result:
    print(row[0])
```

To install pandas:
`pip install pandas`